# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in splashform

Tags: c#, splash-screen

I wanted my program to show a loading message while it checks if the program has connected to a device... but i get an error when i try to close the splashform using the code

```
SplashForm.CloseForm();
```

the actual splashform code is...

```
class SplashForm
{
    //Delegate for cross thread call to close
    private delegate void CloseDelegate();

    //The type of form to be displayed as the splash screen.
    private static SplashForm splashForm;

    static public void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        // Make sure it is only launched once.

        if (splashForm != null)
            return;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashForm.ShowForm));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();           
    }

    static private void ShowForm()
    {
        splashForm = new SplashForm();
        Application.Run(splashForm);
    }

    static public void CloseForm()
    {
        splashForm.Invoke(new CloseDelegate(SplashForm.CloseFormInternal));
    }

    static private void CloseFormInternal()
    {
        splashForm.Close();
    }
...
}
```

in this code... I get a error message as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the line

```
 splashForm.Invoke(new CloseDelegate(SplashForm.CloseFormInternal));
```

what is the reason and solution?

Comment: I am using the same splash form for other process also in the same program. It works there but doesn't work for this particular code where i check for device connect.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` message is the trademark of the NullReferenceException. Here, it means that your `splashForm` field is null.

Make sure that you have 1) called `SplashForm.ShowSplashScreen()` before you call `SplashForm.CloseForm()` and 2) consider calling `thread.Join()` in `ShowSplashScreen()` so you can be sure that by the time you leave that method, `splashForm` is not null.